# Control page behavior by key board

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I need control the behavior page by  key board ... I was trying like this:

```
this.showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand = function (data, event) {
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 49) {
            alert("Combination done !");
        }
    };
```

And I set the binding in a secction, after I've set the bindings in a div, and the result was unsuccessfully ... So what I need is that the behavior of my page can be controlled by keyboard ... That my user can make this combination: Crtl + 1, ctrl + 2, whatever and that by knockout I can show, hide (modal), apply or cleannode bindings, and another things ... It's possible ?? Thanks ...

**UPDATE**

Here is my view model:

```
Billing.BillingViewModel = function () {

    this.billingDate = ko.observable();
    this.billingCode = ko.observable();
    this.billingId = ko.observable();
    this.billingIva = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingSubTotal = ko.observable(0);

    this.billingTotal = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingObservations = ko.observable("");
    this.billingDetails = ko.observableArray();
    this.billingState = ko.observable();

    this.billingClient = new Billing.ClientViewModel();
    this.billingCurrentProductSelected = new Billing.ProductViewModel();
    this.showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand = function (data, event) {
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 49) {
            alert("Combination done !");
        }
    };
};
```

Here is when apply the bindings:

```
Billing.SetViewModel = function () {

    theMainViewModel = Billing.PrepareBilling();
    theManagerViewModel = new Billing.ManagerBillingViewModel();
    theGeneralViewModel = new Billing.GeneralViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel.Billing, $("#" + Billing.BillingHeaderSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel.Billing, $("#" + Billing.BillFooterSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel.Billing, $("#" + Billing.BillProductChoosenSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel.Billing, $("#" + Billing.BillDetailsSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel.FinishBilling, $("#" + Billing.BillFinishSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theManagerViewModel, $("#" + Billing.ManagerSecction)[0]);

    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel, $("#" + Billing.BillActionsSecction)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel, $("#" + Billing.SelectorModalSearcherCustomerId)[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(theMainViewModel, $("#" + Billing.SelectorModalSearcherProductId)[0]);
    //ko.applyBindings(theGeneralViewModel, $("#" + Billing.BillGeneralSecction)[0]);

    theManagerViewModel.theBillings.push(theMainViewModel);
    Billing.SetMask();
};
```

And here is my secction tag control (HTML):

```
<section id="BillHeaderSecction" **data-bind="event: { keypress: billingClient.showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand }, valueupdate: 'afterkeydown'"**>
                <input type="hidden" id="hdfBillingId" name="BillingId" data-bind="value: billingId" />
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 30%">
                            <label>Cliente</label>
                            <input style="width: 100%" type="text" readonly name="Client" id="txtClient" data-bind="value: billingClient.name" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 5%"></td>
                        <td style="width: 30%">
                            <label>Fecha</label>
                            <input style="width: 100%" type="text" readonly name="CreationDate" id="txtCreationDate" data-bind="value: billingDate" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 5%"></td>
                        <td style="width: 30%">
                            <label>Código</label>
                            <input style="width: 100%" type="text" readonly name="BillingCode" id="txtBillingCode" data-bind="value: billingCode" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
```

PD: I've put on bold the secction tag that I want the being controlled by keyboard

Comment: Yes that is possible. Show the rest of your code. Where is the event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keydown` and `keypress` will give you different values for `event.keyCode`. I guess you have to use `keydown` instead.

Look this [Keyevent Tester](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)

I just tested your code with keydown and keypress events:

```
  ...

  var showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand = function (event) {
       if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 49) {
        alert("Combination done ! (Fired by keydown event)");
      }
  };
  window.onkeydown = showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand; // alert 49
  window.onkeypress = showSearcherCustomerKeyCommand; // alert 33
```

And... `event` will be the first parameter passed to your function.

http://jsfiddle.net/01teg8yL/2/